# davinci dont show videos on timeline and dont play them

Tags: linux-mint, video-editing

I'm new user of Linux. I have Mint. I wanted to edit my video using Davinci. After following few tutorials it's finally on my computer, but now I can't play video inside of it and it doesn't even show frames of that video.

I used `ffmpeg` to convert my files into `mp4` (didn't work), and `mov`. Still not working. Please help I dont want to use `kdenlive` because it sucks.

[image]

EDIT: I have OpenCL
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The free Linux version of Davinci does not support the widely used h.264 codec (I guess your mp4 and MOV is encoded this way as most mp4). The list of supported codecs can be found here https://documents.blackmagicdesign.com/SupportNotes/DaVinci_Resolve_16_Supported_Codec_List.pdf

So your only solution is to use another codec like ProRes or MPEG4, by converting it using `ffmpeg` for instance.

Try maybe:

```
$ ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libxvid output.MOV
```

(Sorry, I can't test)

Comment: Thanks for answer, after this converting still not working. I already learned how to use 'kdenlive' and (at this moment) I don't need DaVinci.

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure then as I'm not a Davinci user. Maybe try to find the error logs and paste them here.